# sorting an list by 'datetime'

Tags: python, django

I have the following:

```
appleCreated = Apple.objects.filter(fruit=fruit.id).latest().created
bananaCreated = Banana.objects.filter(fruit=fruit.id).latest().created
lemonCreated = Lemon.objects.filter(fruit=fruit.id).latest().created
orangeCreated = Orange.objects.filter(fruit=fruit.id).latest().created
```

The `.created` is a `models.DateTimeField()`

I need to find the most recent `datetime` (I don't need to know which one it is) out of the four. I know I need to use `.sort(...)` or `sorted(...)` but the documentation is just to dense I I don't understand things like `key=lambda`, `item:item[0]` and `key=itemgetter(0)` WTF!?!?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but shouldn't

```
max(appleCreated, bananaCreated, lemonCreated, orangeCreated)
```

suffice?

Comment: It suffices and saves me typing the same answer.

Comment: I only ask this question because I thought using something like `select_related` would be less of a DB hit then `n` number of calls for `n` number of tables I am comparing